# Joining two file with sed awk separated by comma

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have two files.

**file1.txt**

```
example1
example2
example3
```

**file2.txt**

```
testing1
testing2
testing3
```

I am trying to join the values from these two files into a new comma separated file, with output

**desired output**

```
example1,testing1
example2,testing2
example3,testing3
```

Could anyone help to do this in awk/sed ?
thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `paste`:

```
paste -d, file1 file2
example1,testing1
example2,testing2
example3,testing3
```

Or, you can use `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0; next} {print a[FNR], $0}' file1 file2
example1,testing1
example2,testing2
example3,testing3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'Rfile2' file1 | sed 'N;y/\n/,/'
```

The first sed script reads a line from file1 then a line from file2. The second script takes this output and reads two lines at a time replacing the newline between the lines by a comma.

N.B. This expects each file1/2 to be the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pr` other than `paste` command

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file1
example1
example2
example3

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file2
testing1
testing2
testing3

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ pr -mtJS',' file1 file2
example1,testing1
example2,testing2
example3,testing3
```

Comment: if file1 and file2 records have something matching, can pr join based on the matching records?

Comment: it just joins blindly pr will not see any matching